# A part of an I.M.O problem

Tags: geometry

Let $a$ be the base of a triangle and $a+b$ be its perimeter. Using the fact that area of triangle is maximum when the other two sides are equal, prove that among all quadrilaterals with fixed perimeter square has the greatest area.

Comment: This is just a isoperimetric problem; you could separate the quadrilateral in two triangles and use the property on the triangles from you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

- Show two neighbored sides should be equal by your theorem.
- You get a rhombus, among which square has the greatest area.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There are two triangles formed in every quadrilateral. You will get *all* sides are equal using the triangle fact. You have a Rhombus with all sides equal, now show using the same triangular fact that diagonals are equal.

Comment: I had a tough time deciding the accepted answer. Thank you Rakesh, for your answer :P